# Git how to make an empty commit with two parents

Tags: git, git-commit, cherry-pick

I’ve some issues finding the right git command for the job.

A place I work at is currently switching source control (TFVC -> Git). However, the old version in TFVC still needs bug fixing from time to time.

I’ve handled that by creating a build with some PowerShell scripts that ensure that my “tfvc-merge” branch contains those changes.

So here is what I do afterwards.

- Checkout from integration branch
- I cherry-pick the commit from “tfvc-merge” branch to my
  “mergerhandler” branch
- (my Issue) Now I wanna make an empty commit that have 2 parents.
  First parent is the last commit i have made on "MergeHandler" branch, next
  parent is the commit of the “tfvc-merge” branch.

I tried to draw it up. So basically, the empty commit at the pull request will have the parent of 1 and 2 in my drawing.

[image: Cherry-Pick Strategy]

I've been searching around, for a few hours without finding the right way to do this. So it would be nice with a hint that could point me in the right direction. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### TL;DR

I think you just want `git merge -s ours`.

#### Description

Cherry picking some existing commit makes a new commit that *does not* link back to the original commit (the new commit has a single parent; this parent is the commit that was `HEAD` when you ran `git cherry-pick`).  The drawing you made shows commit #2 with *two* parents, as if your cherry-pick was a merge.  Hence I'm not sure I understand the situation itself correctly.

The phrase *empty commit* is one that Git itself uses, but I find very misleading: commits do not normally have an empty *tree* object (see [Is git's semi-secret empty tree object reliable, and why is there not a symbolic name for it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9765453/1256452)); what's empty about a commit made with `git commit --allow-empty` is the *difference* between that commit and its parent.

There are several ways to make such a commit, obviously including `git commit --allow-empty`, but that first method won't make a *merge* commit.  The only user-facing command that makes merge commits is `git merge`.  This leaves you with the problem of "merging without merging", perhaps, if that phrase even means anything.  Sometimes it does: `git merge -s ours`.

(Note that since a merge commit has *two* parents, using the phrase "empty commit" to talk about this merge makes even less sense than it did when talking about a single-parent commit, because there are *two* diffs to make against the merge commit's two parents.  It's likely that if one is empty, the other is not.)

When you run `git merge`, you may supply a *merge strategy* name.  Git has four built in strategies, named `recursive`, `resolve`, `octopus`, and `ours`.  The normal one that people encounter during normal merges is `recursive`.  The `resolve` strategy is a simplified variant of `-s recursive` that is almost the same thing (the two differ only in the relatively rare case of a merge with multiple merge bases).  The `octopus` strategy is the one Git uses when you make a true merge with *more* than two parents, which we won't discuss at all here.  That leaves `-s ours`.  Before we get to it, let's take a brief moment to review the normal (recursive/resolve) method:

1. You check out some particular branch: `git checkout mainline`.
2. You run `git merge sidebranch`.

At this point, Git computes a *merge base* between the tip commit of `mainline`—the commit to which the branch name points, which I will call `L` for left/local/`--ours`—and the tip commit of `sidebranch`, which I will call `R` for right/remote/`--theirs`:

```
...--o--*--o--L   <-- mainline
         \
          o----R   <-- sidebranch
```

The merge base is a point where the two branches join up: here, it's commit `*`.  Git then, in essence, computes two `git diff`s:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-base> <hash-of-L>   # what we did
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-base> <hash-of-R>   # what they did
```

Git then tries to *combine* the two sets of changes, making those combined changes apply to the contents of the merge base `*`, and if all goes well, Git makes a new *merge commit* `M`, with `L` as its first parent and `R` as its second parent:

```
...--o--*--o--L--M   <-- mainline
         \      /
          o----R   <-- sidebranch
```

Comparing (diffing) `L` vs `M` will show the changes that this merge obtained from `*`-vs-`R` that were not already in `*`-vs-`L`.  That is, we picked up their work.  Comparing `R` vs `M` will show the changes that this merge obtained from `*`-vs-`L` that were not already in `*`-vs-`R`.  That is, we also *kept* our work.

#### The `-s ours` strategy

What `-s ours` does is quite simple.  Instead of bothering with all the `diff`-ing, Git just keeps the tree from `L`.  Git makes the new merge commit with `L` as its first parent and `R` as its second parent, so the *graph* looks exactly the same:

```
...--o--*--o--L--M   <-- mainline
         \      /
          o----R   <-- sidebranch
```

But now if we run `git diff mainline^1 mainline` to compare `L` and `M`, the output is *empty*.  If we run `git diff sidebranch mainline` to compare `R` and `M`, they can be completely different.  Git has *completely ignored* the contents of commit `R`: it has made `M` using the contents of `L`.

If you call an empty diff an "empty commit", then `L` vs `M` is just such an empty commit.  But there's still `R` vs `M` as part of this merge commit, so as we noted above, the phrase "empty commit" does not really make sense here.

#### A long aside

The whole thing would make much more sense if there were an existing merge commit from the old tvfc branch to the new branches:

```
  ...--o--M--o--<arbitrarily complex work>--I   <-- integration
         /
...--o--*   <-- tvfc
```

which over time becomes:

```
  ...--o--M--o--<arbitrarily complex work>--I   <-- integration
         /
...--o--*--o--<arbitrarily complex work>-----X   <-- tvfc
```

In this case, any and all new commits added to `tvfc` itself can simply be merged to `integration` with `git checkout integration; git merge tvfc` as the merge base of `integration` and `tvfc` is now commit `*`.  Git will diff `*` vs `X` to see what they changed, and combine this with `*` vs `I` to see what you changed.  After combining these changes, Git will make a new merge commit `N` and the new merge base in the future will be `X` itself:

```
  ...--o--M--o--<arbitrarily complex work>--I--N   <-- integration
         /                                    /
...--o--*--o--<arbitrarily complex work>-----X   <-- tvfc
```

but that seems not to be what you are doing.  I wonder a bit here if you are simply *setting up* this situation now.  If so, the `git merge -s ours` command above is probably what you want.

Comment: Thank you for the very well written and detailed answer. Keep up the good work.